# ViewPager indicator like in Nexus 5 launcher

Tags: android, geometry, pager, indicator

Yeah, I know about Jake Wharton's library. But do anyone know pager indicator, like in Nexus 5 launcher:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dALAH.png

So, circles are switching with effect - big circle became small and small is shifting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by changing round big image to small image resources & viceversa dynamically on OnPageChangeListener method of viewPager.

Comment: Maybe, maybe... But what about more "native" or any complete solution?